# Insert default values if not exist in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I have one question about SQL Server: how to dynamically load default values for all tables if 9999 values does not exist in the tables?

The database has three tables. I want load default 9999 values for unique column

- if datatype is `varchar` then pass `NA` value
- if datatype is `int` then pass 0 value
- if datatype is `date` then pass 1900-01-01 value

Here sourceFiedls table is maintain all table related fields information.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[dept]
(
    [deptid] [INT] NULL,
    [dname] [VARCHAR](50) NULL,
    [loc] [VARCHAR](50) NULL
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[emp]
(
    [eid] [INT] NULL,
    [ename] [VARCHAR](50) NULL,
    [doj] [DATE] NULL,
    [sal] [MONEY] NULL,
    [deptid] [INT] NULL
) 

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[loc]
(
    [locid] [INT] NULL,
    [locname] [VARCHAR](50) NULL
) 

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[sourceFields]
(
    [tablename] [VARCHAR](50) NULL,
    [tablecolumns] [VARCHAR](50) NULL
) 

INSERT INTO [dbo].[dept] ([deptid], [dname], [loc]) 
VALUES (1, N'abc', N'hy')
GO

INSERT INTO [dbo].[emp] ([eid], [ename], [doj], [sal], [deptid]) 
VALUES (1, N'ab', CAST(N'1988-10-04' AS Date), 100.0000, 10)
GO

INSERT INTO [dbo].[loc] ([locid], [locname]) VALUES (1, N'hyd')
GO

INSERT INTO [dbo].[sourceFields] ([tablename], [tablecolumns]) 
VALUES (N'dept', N'deptid'), (N'dept', N'dname'), (N'dept', N'loc'),
       (N'emp', N'eid'), (N'emp', N'ename'), (N'emp', N'doj'),
       (N'emp', N'sal'), (N'emp', N'deptid'), (N'loc', N'locid'), 
       (N'loc', N'locname')
GO
```

Based on above table I want check the data if 9999 values exist or not.

For dept table :

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dept WHERE  deptid=9999 )
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[dept] ([deptid], [dname], [loc]) 
    VALUES (9999, 'NA', 'NA')
END
```

For `Emp` table :

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM emp WHERE  eid=9999 )
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[emp] ([eid], [ename], [doj], [sal], [deptid]) 
    VALUES (9999, 'NA', CAST('1900-01-01' AS Date), 0, 0)
END
```

For `Loc` table :

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM loc WHERE  locid=9999 )
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[loc] ([locid], [locname]) 
    VALUES (9999, 'NA')
END
```

Here I have written 3 statements for 3 tables checking default values exist or not.
Instead of these 3 statements, how to write a dynamic query like using cursor concept and table loop iterate values - if exist or not if not exist then insert.
this table maintain tablenames and filed names to generate dynamic insert statments and values.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Tableinfo](
    [TableName] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [ColumnsList] [varchar](1000) NULL
) 

INSERT [dbo].[Tableinfo] ([TableName], [ColumnsList]) VALUES (N'dept',N'deptid,dname,loc')
INSERT [dbo].[Tableinfo] ([TableName], [ColumnsList]) VALUES (N'emp', N'eid,ename,doj,sal,deptid')
INSERT [dbo].[Tableinfo] ([TableName], [ColumnsList]) VALUES (N'loc', N'locid,locname')
```

Can you please tell me how to write dynamic query for inserting default values into a table?

Answer (score 0):

here's a rough idea, see how I am retrieving the SID/PK column, have a pattern to match the PK or use information_schema.tables, table_constraints, etc. to retrieve them:

```
DECLARE 
    @delStatement VARCHAR(MAX);

DECLARE def CURSOR
FOR SELECT 
        'IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT top 1 1 FROM ' + tablename + ' WHERE  ' + tablecolumns + ' = 9999 )
       BEGIN
          INSERT [dbo].[dept] ([deptid], [dname], [loc]) VALUES (9999, ''NA'', ''NA'')
       END'
    From [dbo].[sourceFields]
    where
        tablecolumns = tablename + 'id';
OPEN def;

FETCH NEXT FROM def INTO 
    @delStatement;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        PRINT @delStatement;
        --Exec(@delStatement) UNCOMMENT THIS
        FETCH NEXT FROM def INTO 
            @delStatement;
    END;
CLOSE def;
DEALLOCATE def;
```

Comment: alex;Could you please provide full logic.it will hepfull